# Being holomorphic at a single point does not imply to be $C^{\infty}$ at the point

Tags: complex-analysis

I read a claim such that "being holomorphic at a single point does not imply to be $C^{\infty}$ at the point" which is the second answer in the following post [Holomorphic functions and real functions: continuity of partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149146/holomorphic-functions-and-real-functions-continuity-of-partial-derivatives)

The definition is from Wiki: "holomorphic at a point $z_0$" means not just differentiable at $z_0$, but differentiable everywhere within some neighbourhood of $z_0$ in the complex plane.

Can you give me an example for this claim?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion with definitions here. If $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of a point it is certainly $C^{\infty}$ in that neighborhood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a matter of conflicting definitions.  If a holomorphic function at a point is defined to be complex-differentiable in a neighborhood of the point (which is the standard definition), then a holomorphic function is always $C^\infty$.  On the other hand, if a holomorphic function at a point is just required to be complex-differentiable at the point itself, then it need not be $C^\infty$.  The claim which you linked is using the second definition, not the first.

For a simple example, let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be any function which is differentiable at $0$ with $g'(0)=0$, but not $C^\infty$ in any neighborhood of $0$ (for instance, $g(x)=x|x|$).  Then $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=g(\operatorname{Re}(z))$ is complex-differentiable at any $z$ with $\operatorname{Re}(z)=0$ (and $f'(z)=0$ at those points), but is not $C^\infty$ in any neighborhood of such a point.

Comment: Can you give me an example such that $f^{\prime}(z_0)$ exist but $f^{\prime\prime}(z_0)$ does not exist?